# How to make a config singleton in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, singleton, symfony6

Good morning,

I'm starting to learn symfony.
I would like to create a class to manage the settings that are in parameters - Services.yml.

```
    parameters:
  config:
    global:
      db.host: xxx
      db.port: ''
      db.user: yyy ...
```

I created a class Config in singleton and would like to call it anywhere in my application.

The problem is that the only way I found is to pass the ContainerBagInterface service in __construct to load a variable with all the information I need.

```
    private function __construct(ContainerBagInterface $params)
    {
        $this->config = $this->params->get('config');
    }

    public static function getInstance(ContainerBagInterface $params): Config
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self($params);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

I always need to pass $params I wish I didn't have to do that.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Delete the singleton and use dependency injection instead. See the documentation of how this is done/works/flies with Symfony, if you have a problem deleting the singleton class file let me know.

Comment: As mentioned above, best to avoid singletons especially when just getting started unless you are dealing with legacy code issues.  It is possible to do something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334485/symfony-configure-class-from-service-yaml-with-static-default-value/75421121#75421121) but not recommended.

Comment: this is not the symfony way. you want todo something which in symfony terms neither is adviced nor makes it any sense.